# Does anyone have Magento 2.3 ERD database diagram?

Tags: magento2.3

Does anyone have Magento 2.3.x ERD database diagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There 2.1.3 DB diagram that create by anna, you can see this at

https://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-2-1-3-database-diagram/

I think for the core magento2 (Product, Category, Order, etc) not much different than 2.3x

Answer (score 1):

An ER diagram is a visualization of tables within a database and how they relate to each other. This article contains a few ER diagrams to help you visualize the relationship between a handful of common Magento database tables.[image]

For further reference: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016729931-Magento-Entity-Relationship-Diagrams